# getting nan for every step in keras.model.fit

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I have a file with 26 variables, off which 25 are x values and 26th value is the y value.  I want to fit a linear function predicting the value of y from x's.  I used the below program

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import Sequential
import numpy as np

arr = np.loadtxt('../data/TscoreTest.csv',skiprows=1,delimiter=',')

x = arr[:,0:25]
x = x.astype(float)
y = arr[:,-1]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1,input_shape=(25,), kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', activation='linear'))
sgd = SGD()
model.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss='mse',metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(x,y, batch_size=1, epochs=30, shuffle=False)
```

But it always return nan
1/23 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan
22/23 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan
23/23 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan
Epoch 30/30

I checked the x and y and they have valid float values.  What is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: You have used a `linear` activation. At some point the output is more than what `float32` can accomodate, hence the `nan` values

Answer (score 0):

Try converting '**mse**' to '**mae**'. As the values of loss and mean_squared_error are too high, you are getting this error. Please reconfigure your model with **Adam** optimizer and run again.